# Model stretched when window resize OpenGL 3.2

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I've set up a window (in MFC) that contains on OpenGL 3.2 rendering context. Since it's with OpenGL 3.2 I want to use shaders ect, so I'm biulding my projection and view matrix by hand. I've used [this](http://www.rastertek.com/gl40tut04.html) tutorial as an input to build them and pass them to my shader.

The problem now is that (even in the example of the tutorial) when I resize my window, the model is stretched.

This is the code I use to build my matrices (I rebuild them and send them to my shader every the window is refreshed).

View Matrix:

```
float zAxis[3], xAxis[3], yAxis[3]; 
float length, result1, result2, result3;

// zAxis = normal(lookAt - position)
zAxis[0] = lookAt[0] - m_position[0];
zAxis[1] = lookAt[1] - m_position[1];
zAxis[2] = lookAt[2] - m_position[2];
length = sqrt((zAxis[0] * zAxis[0]) + (zAxis[1] * zAxis[1]) + (zAxis[2] * zAxis[2]));
zAxis[0] = zAxis[0] / length;
zAxis[1] = zAxis[1] / length;
zAxis[2] = zAxis[2] / length;

// xAxis = normal(cross(up, zAxis))
xAxis[0] = (up[1] * zAxis[2]) - (up[2] * zAxis[1]);
xAxis[1] = (up[2] * zAxis[0]) - (up[0] * zAxis[2]);
xAxis[2] = (up[0] * zAxis[1]) - (up[1] * zAxis[0]);
length = sqrt((xAxis[0] * xAxis[0]) + (xAxis[1] * xAxis[1]) + (xAxis[2] * xAxis[2]));
xAxis[0] = xAxis[0] / length;
xAxis[1] = xAxis[1] / length;
xAxis[2] = xAxis[2] / length;

// yAxis = cross(zAxis, xAxis)
yAxis[0] = (zAxis[1] * xAxis[2]) - (zAxis[2] * xAxis[1]);
yAxis[1] = (zAxis[2] * xAxis[0]) - (zAxis[0] * xAxis[2]);
yAxis[2] = (zAxis[0] * xAxis[1]) - (zAxis[1] * xAxis[0]);

// -dot(xAxis, position)
result1 = ((xAxis[0] * m_position[0]) + (xAxis[1] * m_position[1]) + (xAxis[2] * m_position[2])) * -1.0f;

// -dot(yaxis, eye)
result2 = ((yAxis[0] * m_position[0]) + (yAxis[1] * m_position[1]) + (yAxis[2] * m_position[2])) * -1.0f;

// -dot(zaxis, eye)
result3 = ((zAxis[0] * m_position[0]) + (zAxis[1] * m_position[1]) + (zAxis[2] * m_position[2])) * -1.0f;

viewMatrix[0]  = xAxis[0];
viewMatrix[1]  = yAxis[0];
viewMatrix[2]  = zAxis[0];
viewMatrix[3]  = 0.0f;

viewMatrix[4]  = xAxis[1];
viewMatrix[5]  = yAxis[1];
viewMatrix[6]  = zAxis[1];
viewMatrix[7]  = 0.0f;

viewMatrix[8]  = xAxis[2];
viewMatrix[9]  = yAxis[2];
viewMatrix[10] = zAxis[2];
viewMatrix[11] = 0.0f;

viewMatrix[12] = result1;
viewMatrix[13] = result2;
viewMatrix[14] = result3;
viewMatrix[15] = 1.0f;
```

Projection Matrix:

```
float screenAspect = (float)rcClient.Width() / (float)rcClient.Height();
float fov = 3.14159265358979323846f / 4.0f;
float zfar = 1000.0;
float znear = 0.1f;

projectionMatrix[0]  = 1.0f / (screenAspect * tan( fov * 0.5f));
projectionMatrix[1]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[2]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[3]  = 0.0f;

projectionMatrix[4]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[5]  = 1.0f / tan( fov * 0.5f);
projectionMatrix[6]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[7]  = 0.0f;

projectionMatrix[8]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[9]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[10] = zfar / (zfar - znear);
projectionMatrix[11] = 1.0f;

projectionMatrix[12] = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[13] = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[14] = (-znear * zfar) / (zfar - znear);
projectionMatrix[15] = 0.0f;
```

And in my shader I use them this way:

```
#version 150

in vec3 inputPosition;
in vec3 inputColor;

out vec3 color;

uniform mat4 worldMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldMatrix * vec4(inputPosition, 1.0f);

    color = inputColor;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here?

Comment: Are you rebuilding your projection matrix after window resize? Is `rcClient.Width()` actual window width and not cached one (the one that was requested on window creation, and wasn't updated properly after resize)?

Comment: Yes I'm doing it in the draw function of the view, which is called after the window is resized, and the width and height (I've checked) are the current ones, not the cached.

Comment: The "funny" thing is that, I've just tried, even GLM it doesn't work. It's stretched anyway.

Comment: Code in given tutorial looks unreasonably huge for this simple task. Please ensure that you re-passing matrices to shader at each frame, and that you calling `glViewport` after resize (or even at each frame too). If problem persists, show complete code (upload it somewhere if too big for question format).

Comment: Maybe that's the thing. I never call glViewport because the tutorial didn't use it, so I thought it was unnecessary. In the older version of the program I'm building we used it (in fact I'm converting our engine to OGL 3 or above from OGL 1.1).
You're saying that I need to call it even in OGL 3.2 and using shaders?

Comment: Yes, you should always use `glViewport` after you change viewport size. It affects conversion from normalized device coordinates to screen space, which have nothing to do with shaders. After window creation it _could_ be skipped, because window creation sets default viewport size anyway.

Comment: I've set the viewport and now it works fine. How did I not think about it. Now I wonder why in the tutorial it's not used -.-

Answer (score -1):

Don't use glViewport since you can just use shaders which is the preferred way.

Can you change your projection matrix to:

```
float projectionMatrix[4][4];
projectionMatrix[0][0]  = 1.0f / (screenAspect * tan( fov * 0.5f));
projectionMatrix[0][1]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[0][2]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[0][3]  = 0.0f;

projectionMatrix[1][0]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[1][1]  = 1.0f / tan( fov * 0.5f);
projectionMatrix[1][2]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[1][3]  = 0.0f;

projectionMatrix[2][0]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[2][1]  = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[2][2] = (-znear -zfar) / (znear-zfar);
projectionMatrix[2][3] = 2.0f * zfar * znear / (znear-zfar);

projectionMatrix[3][0] = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[3][1] = 0.0f;
projectionMatrix[3][2] = 1.0;
projectionMatrix[3][3] = 0.0f;
```

I am not sure about your UVN matrix, but it may not be the problem since you got it working after using glViewport.
Anyway, instead of generating your matrices you can use GLM. Code example on building the projection, UVN, translation matrices, etc is given here: [glm code example](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/code.html)
I think that this tutorials explain transformations well enough: http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/

Comment: You still need to set the viewport to the window size when using shaders. The viewport transformation is still part of the pipeline when using shaders, and is not replaced by programmable functionality. It's part of the fixed function block between vertex and fragment shader.